# определения по информатике

Tags: информатика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, что понимают под терминами:
1) разрядность слова информации
2) разрядность команд

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если нужно определение - пожалуйте в wiki или словарь.
Если же нужно понять, то объясню на пальцах. Компьютеры оперируют двоичной арифметикой. Так удобнее из-за особенностей электрических сигналов. Удобно принять какое-то фиксированное значение напряжения за логическую 1, а отсутствие сигнала (0-вой потенциал) - за логический 0. Получается, минимальная единица информации - это бит, имеющий два значения. Это и есть разряд. Физически он реализуется одним проводником. Соответственно, разрядность - кол-во этих самых разрядов, которыми мы можем что-то описать. Или битов. Слово же это тоже некая величина, которая характеризуется разрядностью регистров процессора. Для современных процессоров это 4 байта или 32 бита. Больший набор информации за раз процессор переварить не может. И со словом он может работать как с единой величиной.

Разрядность команд - я бы ее понял как кол-во битов необходимых для описания самой длинной команды процессора. Да, процессоры бывают с командами фиксированной длины и переменной. Первое - это RISC-архитектура, а второе - CISC-архитектура. В первом случае есть ограниченный набор простых команд, при этом могут отсутствовать операции умножения/деления: они реализуются через сложение-вычитание и пр. В этом есть свои "+" и свои "-". Во втором набор команд сложный. Есть много разных команд: деление, умножение, синусы, косинусы. Только плата за это - существенно более сложный декодер команд и за счет более сложной структуры сложнее наращивать тактовые частоты. Но теперь уже эти принципы в чистом виде не применяются. Современные процессоры типа Intel Core2Duo и Athlon с виду - CISC, а внутри RISC-ядро.

Answer (score 0):

Разрядность - число сигналов на линии. В частном случае разрядность шины и соответственно защёлки [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)
Без знания электроники это не понять.

Команда - данные на шине, нет разницы между разрядностью слова, так как слово и есть команда(размер данных, тоесть разрядность квантуется и фиксирована).

Comment: Не знал бы - ничего бы не понял ^^"